# How to properly use structs in c++?

Tags: c++, struct, header-files

I have a data structure in a header file of a player and a goblin that looks like this:

```
#ifndef GLOBALVAR_H
#define GLOBALVAR_H

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

struct Player {
    int x = 1, y = 1;
    int health = 100;
    int symbol = '@';
};

struct Goblin {
    int x, y;
    int health = 100;
    int symbol = 'G';
};

#endif
```

I also have a data structure in a header file for the screen that looks like this:

```
#ifndef SCREEN_H
#define SCREEN_H

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

struct Screen {
    char screen[21][34] = {
        "#################################",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#...............................#",
        "#################################"
    };
};

#endif
```

Finally, I have the main and generate c++ files that look like this respectively:

```
// main 'hub' for game

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#include "screen.h"
#include "generate.h"
#include "globalVar.h"

using namespace std;

bool running = true;

int main() {
    struct Player p;
    struct Screen s;

    while(running) {

        system("cls");
        
        s.screen[p.y][p.x] = p.symbol;

        draw();

        p.health--;

        system("pause>nul");
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```
// generates the map and draws the screen

#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#include "screen.h"
#include "globalVar.h"

using namespace std;

int generate() {


    return 0;
}

int draw() {
    struct Screen s;
    struct Player player;

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cout << s.screen[i] << endl;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        cout << "HP: " << player.health << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

When I run main.cpp I want it to display a '@' symbol at 1, 1 of the array. When I run the code it instead displays a period in the place of it. What is happening here?

Image of what's being displayed:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZUh3.jpg

Comment: Why does each method declare their own separate Screen object?

Comment: The `Screen s` in your `main` function has no relationship whatsoever to the `Screen s` in your `draw` function. They have the same name, but they're separate variables in separate scopes. You might want to make `draw` a member function of the `Screen` struct and call `s.draw()`, for instance.

Comment: in `main` you declare a Screen.  When you call draw(), you declare _another_ screen, and draw that.  These are _unrelated_ objects, each with their own array.  If you want to make changes to the array in main, then you have to pass your screen from main to the draw function, so it reflects the changes.

Comment: This doesn't addresss the question, but don't `#include <windows.h>`, especially in headers, unless you absolutely need it; it's huge, and kills compile times. Of course, that directive here could just be an artifact from creating a minimal example.

Comment: unlike in C, there is no need to put 'struct' before every use of a struct. Simply put 'Screen s' instead of 'struct Screen s;'

Comment: Why is `draw` returning a constant 0?  If a function doesn't need to return a value, have the function declared as returning `void`, example:  `void draw()`.

Comment: Tip: In C++ think about classes and, where necessary, inheritance. There's no reason to have two almost identical `struct`s here. Have *one* `class` you instantiate twice.

Comment: Tip: Store data like your maps in plain text files you can read in, or even better, generate them in code automatically.

Comment: Tip: Using `system()` to effect clearing the screen and waiting for input is *extremely* in efficient and highly non-portable. Windows supports [ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) which has a ton of capability if you print out the right escape codes. This is super easy to do, and was how a lot of very simple DOS programs managed to control the screen.

Comment: @EduardoMarotoCampos I don't usually do that. Not sure why I did it here.

Answer (score 1):

You have created two different `Screen`s. The one in `main()` is completely different from the one in `draw()`, because they are in different scopes. You can pass a `Screen` as an argument to `draw()` to fix this.

You can also make `draw()` a function of `Screen`, as Nathan pointed out in the comments, and then call `s.draw()` in `main()`.

Also, unlike in C, there is no need to put `struct` before every use of a `struct`. Simply put `Screen s;` instead of `struct Screen s;`

Example of `draw()` taking a parameter of type `Screen`:

```
int draw(Screen s) {
    Player player;

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        cout << s.screen[i] << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        cout << "HP: " << player.health << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example of `draw()` in `Screen`:

```
struct Screen {
    static char screen[21][34];

    int draw() {
        Player player; //think about passing this as a parameter instead, not making one every time, because this one is inaccessible to everyone except this function

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            cout << screen[i] << endl;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            cout << "HP: " << player.health << endl;
        }

        return 0;
    }

};
```

Then, call it like:

```
s.draw();
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but how do I define what the screen looks like? I see with a static it needs to be declared, but how do I define how the screen looks like I have done already?

Answer (score 0):

I would go a different route and use inheritance and constructors:

```
    struct Item
    {
        int m_x, m_y; // Every item has a position.
        char m_symbol;
    
        Item (char symbol, int x_pos = 1, int y_pos = 1)
        : m_symbol(symbol), m_x(x_pos), m_y(y_pos)
        { ; }
    };
    
    struct Player : public Item  // A player is an item
    : Item('@', 1, 1)
    {
    };
    
    struct Goblin : public Item // A goblin is an item
    : Item ('G', 5, 4)
    {
    };
    
    std::vector<std::vector<Item *>> game_board;

//...
    Goblin * p_goblin = new Goblin;
    game_board[p_goblin->y][p_goblin->x] = p_goblin;
```